# Jupyterlab highlight print and ctrl+z not returning to edited line

Tags: jupyter-lab

I have recently installed jupyterlab on a new machine and the default behaviour either seems to have changed, or I am lacking some settings. I only have the jupyterlab-pygments enabled. I am unsure how to phrase these "requests" for an efficient search of solution, so I'll try to be descriptive here:

1. In my previous setup, the **print** function used to be highlighted in green, similar to **dict**, **from**, **import** statements. Now, it's only these ones that are highlighted, but **print** no longer is. How can I revert it?
2. When I pressed Ctrl+Z, the notebook used to undo the change AND move the screen to the line that was changed for easier manouvering. How can I recover this behaviour?

Comment: (1) https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/14589

Comment: (2) you may want to open a new issue and test our JupyterLab 4.1 beta to see if this is already fixed